# R plotly - showing distinct label

Tags: r, label, plotly

I am trying to build a spending tracker in R. The dataframe has three attributes which are date, money, and category. I have successfully made a stacked barchart with x-axis= Date and y-axis= sum of money spent, but I am having a trouble with labeling the category to be distinct (not repeated).

[image: Here] is what the chart looks like now, and I want the label to be displayed as A, B, C only.

Here is my code:

```
    dff<- data.frame(today= Sys.Date(), money = 222 , category = "B")
    new_dat<- data.frame(today= Sys.Date()-1, money = 111, category = "A")
    dff<- rbind(dff,new_dat)
    new_dat<- data.frame(today= Sys.Date()-1, money = 222, category = "C")
    dff<- rbind(dff,new_dat)


    plot_ly(dff, type = "bar", x = ~today, y = ~money, color = ~category) %>%
  add_trace(y= ~today, name= ~category) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack') %>%
  add_annotations(text = ~money,
                  x = ~today,
                  y = ~money,
                  xref = 'today',
                  yref = 'money',
                  font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                              color = 'rgb(67, 67, 67)'),
                  showarrow= FALSE
                  )
```

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example. Using `dput`, please include dfff in your post.

Comment: @MLavoie Oops, I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add `showlegend = FALSE` to the second trace. Do you want this?

```
a<- plot_ly(dff, type = "bar", x = ~today, y = ~money, color = ~category) %>%
    add_trace(y= ~today, name= ~category, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
    layout(barmode = 'stack')

a
```

EDIT:
For your follow-up question, you could try this:

```
a<- plot_ly(dff, type = "bar", x = ~today, y = ~money, color = ~category) %>%
  add_trace(y= ~today, name= ~category, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack') %>%   
add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                x = "2018-04-15", y = ~money - 50,
                text = paste(dff[,"money"], '$'),
                font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                showarrow = FALSE) %>% 
add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y',
                x = "2018-04-16", y = "111",
                text = paste("222", '$'),
                font = list(family = 'Arial', size = 12,
                            color = 'rgb(248, 248, 255)'),
                showarrow = FALSE)
```

Comment: Oh I thought showlegend = FALSE would remove the legend, but I guess not! Btw, do you happen to know how to make the value appear on each bar as shown here [link](https://plot.ly/r/horizontal-bar-charts/) Color Palette for Bar Chart?

Comment: I have edited the post with add_annotations(), but it produces an ugly plot :(

Comment: @user9532692 see my edits. Please accept my answer if it answers your question!

Comment: Is there a way to place the add_annotations value to be placed in the middle instead of manually subtracting a value (e.g. y= ~money - 50 in your code)?

Comment: Maybe someone else will come up with a solution, but I don't think there is a way with your current dataset. You can try this `y = dff[,"money"] / 2` but it won't give you what you want